# list of LaTeX math symbol abbrevs together with Unicode char

Tags: unicode, latex, tex

does anyone know a page that list all TeX/LaTeX's math symbols abbrevation together with a unicode character?

i need the glyph to be unicode char, not a image.

i spent 20 min but couldn't find it.

closest i found is http://ia.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:LaTeX_symbols
but it uses images. If it uses unicode char, that'd be perfect.

Comment: By the way, there’s also http://tex.stackexchange.com/ which is better suited for questions revolving around (La)TeX.

Answer (score 4):

Not exaclty what you asked for, but you might find [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) useful depending on exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

At least most of the symbols can be copied/pasted as characters from the `symbols` documentation (in PDF format). Just enter `texdoc symbols` on your command line, or use [this CTAN link [PDF]](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: don't have TeX/LaTeX installed on this machine... that PDF doc list all but when copy pasted into text editor, the glyphs isn't unicode...

Comment: @Xah: “Unicode” is an encoding. The glyphs are either characters or pictures, depending on the type of glyph. If you copy them into a text editor then those that are characters are pasted successfully and can be saved as Unicode.

Comment: @konrad rudolph. somehow it just doesnt work for me. For example, on page 34 near bottom, you have the ≠ symbol. But when copy and pasted, i get this:

x \ne (same as \nequal)

that x there is unicode LATIN SMALL LETTER X.

similar for most symbols that exist in unicode... am not sure if there's other way to copy, or if the doc is simply not using unicode (hard to make the statement precise, since i dont know what sort of format pdf uses... whether it makes sense to say it uses unicode...)

Comment: @Xah: well, in that case the math font used is apparently drawing its own glyphs without regard for Unicode. Since the default (math) font predates modern encoding standards, there isn’t always a mapping. Like I said: sometimes the glyphs are characters, sometimes they are just arbitrary pictures that are assigned to a random codepoint without a proper meaning (thus you get gibberish when pasting them). In this case, [U+DB80](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/db80/index.htm) is apparently used, which is lying in the private use section of Unicode: it doesn’t have a standard meaning.

Comment: @Xah: in summary, I am not aware of any comprehensive mapping of LaTeX symbols to Unicode equivalents. I know that the mappings used internally are incomplete (and this is evidenced by the fact that not all symbols can be copied from the `symbols` manual). You might try to look at the source code of the `utf8.def` file from the `inputenc` package, which contains a mapping of some(!) UTF-8 (not Unicode code points!) byte sequences to LaTeX. But I fear that this won’t help you very much either.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph. Thanks for the informative tips. I think this is a interesting question. I thought there are probably on the web but apparently hard to find or rare. Anyway, i no longer need it, but that pdf doc is quite a good one in its comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols.

Answer (score 1):

This XML file may also be useful: http://www.w3.org/Math/characters/unicode.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably no longer a problem, I thought for reference purposes I would add the following link: [an-extensive-list-of-latex-symbols-and-unicode-equivalents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162385/an-extensive-list-of-latex-symbols-and-unicode-equivalents).